# Connect local ftp server with Android

Tags: android, ftp, server, apache-commons

I have made an ftp server in a Local drive of my laptop and assigned an IP address to it. I want to fetch excel files on that server using my android app and process the data. 
How can I go about this? 
Is Commons Apache the way to it?

Comment: `made an ftp server in a Local drive`. What do you mean by that? And why would the info be of relevance.

Comment: `and assigned an IP address to it`? What do you mean by that? Why would one assingn an ip to a server? And which ip did you assign?

Comment: You should install an ftp client app on your Android device so you can connect to your server. Or write your own Android ftp client app.

Comment: I made one of my drives as an ftp server. And I want to read files on that server with my Android app that I am writing, and show the processed results. What I am trying to use is FTPClient.

Comment: How can a drive be a server? For the rest you are not really giving more info.

Comment: Sorry I meant a folder in one of my drives. Does that help?

Comment: Still nonsense. How can a folder in a drive be a server?

Comment: Or let me try to say it another way, I have an address of format "ftp:// 192.168._._" and I need to fetch a file on that server with code, then read it and process the data depending on what I want, and show the results in my app UI. I am trying to connect to ftp address by apache commons right now

Comment: I do not understand your other way either.

Comment: You can use Ftp4j ; http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/download.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the snippet I made and worked for me.

```
     FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                try {
                    ftpClient.connect("192.168.5.3", 21);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpClient.login("FTP_User", "ravi1998");

                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);

                    InputStream inStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("record.xls");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(inStream);
                    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
                    int row = s.getRows();
                    int col = s.getColumns();

                    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                      for(int c = 0, c< col; c++){
                        Cell z = s.getCell(c, i);
                        String content = z.getContents();
                       }
                    }
```

Comment: Having the username and password hard coded can't be very secure ? or is it ?

Comment: @Demonic218 It's a test code for a personal project

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:make your mobile hotspot on and connect your laptop with that hotspot.

step 2:make sure that your firewall is off. and apache or wampserver is on.

step 3:write ipconfig command in you cmd admin panel and chbeck your ip for wifi.

```
 ipconfig
```

step 4: same ip put in mobile browser it will show wampserver page..

i do this type configration for android to wampserver connection may be its helpful to you.